# how to control postback in checkbox in asp.net C# Ajax with ajax toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, checkbox

when we use UpdatePanel , page refresh when  postback .how can use checkbox without  updatepanel , and use Ajax to post back without page refresh?

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSW" Text="" runat="server"    OnCheckedChanged="lbnHPSettingMenu_Click" />
```

c# code for checkbox is:

```
protected void lbnHPSettingMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ddlSettingLang.DataBind();
            ddlSettingLang.SelectedValue = ListBHPS[0].LangID.ToString();
            ddlSettingPageTheme.DataBind();
            ddlSettingPageTheme.SelectedValue = ListBHPS[0].ThemeID.ToString();
            txtSettingTitle.Text = ListBHPS[0].Title;
            txtSettingDiscription.Text = ListBHPS[0].Discription;
     }
```

how can execute code lbnHPSettingMenu_Click without postback with ajax?

Comment: Then you should go with client side instead of server side coding.

Comment: how can i do?do you have simple code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

insert your `checkbox` inside an `Update Panel`

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
       <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSW" Text="" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="lbnHPSettingMenu_Click" />
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkSW" />
       </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i not use UpdatePanel.

Comment: then use it to prevent postback